# A measure assigning values in $\{0,1\}$ must be a Dirac measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on some measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ such that

$$\mu(B)\in \{0,1\},\quad \forall B\in \mathcal F.$$

Can we show that $\mu$ must be a Dirac measure (under suitable conditions for $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ if needed) or disprove this claim with a counterexample?

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be uncountable and $\mathcal{F}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of sets that are countable or have countable complement. Let $\mu(B)=1$ if $B$ is uncountable and $\mu(B)=0$ for $B$ countable. However, if $\mathcal{F}$ is countably generated and separate points, the answer is yes.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Many thanks for the amazing counterexample. Could you please give me definition of "$\mathcal F$ is countably generated and separate points"?

Comment: There is a countable family such that $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing it. Separating points means that for any two points, there is a measurable set containing only one. The assumption of separating points is actually not needed. Here is the idea: Let $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ be a sequence such that $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of them. For each $i$, pick either $C_i$ or its complement, whatever has measure $1$. The intersection of the resulting sets has measure $1$ and for any $x$ in it, your measure will be $\delta_x$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you very kindly for your explaination

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That sounds like an answer. Maybe post it as one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discuss the case where the sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ is the power set $\mathscr P(\Omega)$ of $\Omega$.

Then: it is consistent with ZFC that, for every set $\Omega$, every $\{0,1\}$-valued measure on $(\Omega, \mathscr P(\Omega))$ is a Dirac measure.  Equivalently: every ultrafilter on $\Omega$ closed under coutable intersections is fixed.

But it is believed to be consistent with ZFC that there exist a set $\Omega$ with $\{0,1\}$-valued measure on $\mathscr P(\Omega)$ that is not Dirac.  The smallest cardinal of such a set is the least of the so-called [**measurable cardinals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal) .

*Summary:* It is consistent with ZFC that no measurable cardinals exist; but (it is believed) it it also consistent that measurable cardinals do exist.

Answer (score 5):

There is a topological characterization for when every $\{0,1\}$-measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is a Dirac point-evaluation measure.

Proposition: Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ be a $\sigma$-algebra that separates points. Then there exists a compact zero-dimensional space $K$ with $X\subseteq K$ with $X$ dense in $K$ and where $R\in\mathcal{M}$ if and only if $R=f^{-1}[\{0\}]\cap X$ for some continuous function $f:K\rightarrow[0,1]$. Furthermore, $R\in\mathcal{M}$ if and only if $R=X\cap S$ for some clopen $S\subseteq K$.

Proof outline: Let $K$ denote the space of all ultrafilters on the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{M}$. Then by identifying each element in $X$ with the Dirac point evaluation measure, we can assume that $X\subseteq K$. If $\mathcal{M}$ is simply an algebra of sets, then $\mathcal{M}$ is precisely the set of all intersections $S\cap X$ for some clopen $S\subseteq K$. The fact that $R\in\mathcal{M}$ if and only if $R=f^{-1}[\{0\}]\cap X$ follows from the observation that $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is the intersection of countably many clopen sets. Q.E.D.

Suppose that $X$ is a dense subspace of a compact Hausdorff space $K$. Then let $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by the sets $f^{-1}[\{0\}]\cap X$ where $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is some continuous function. The above result states that any $\sigma$-algebra that separates points can be put into this form. Then whenever $\mu$ is a $\{0,1\}$-measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$, we can define a function $\phi_\mu:C(K)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by setting $\phi_\mu(f)=\int f|_Xd\mu$. Then observe that $\phi_\mu$ is not only a continuous linear functional, but that whenever $f:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is constant, the function $f|_X$ is constant almost everywhere with respect to $\mu$. Using this fact, we can conclude that $\phi_\mu$ is a ring homomorphism. One can use the compactness of $K$ to show that every ring homomorphism from $C(K)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves the identity mapping must be a point evaluation map. In our case, there will be a unique point $x_\mu\in X$ where $\phi_\mu(f)=\int f|_Xd\mu=f(x_\mu)$ for each $f\in C(K)$.

A regular space is said to be a $P$-space if the intersection of countably many open sets is open. If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a regular space, then the $P$-space coreflection of $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is the regular space $(X,\mathcal{S})$ where $U\in\mathcal{S}$ precisely when for all $x\in U$, there are $U_n\in\mathcal{T}$ for each natural number $n$ where $x\in\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty U_n$. It is easy to show that the $P$-space coreflection of a regular space is always a $P$-space. We shall let $(X)_{\aleph_1}$ denote the $P$-space reflection of $X$.

Proposition: Let $\mathcal{F}=\{R\in\mathcal{M}:\mu(R)=1\}$. Then the filter $\mathcal{F}$ converges to $x_\mu$ in the $P$-space coreflection $(K)_{\aleph_1}$.

Proof: Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of the point $x_\mu$ with respect to the space $(K)_{\aleph_1}$. Then there are open sets $U_n$ with respect to the compact topology on $K$ where $x_\mu\in\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty U_n\subseteq U$. For each $n$, let $f_n:K\rightarrow[0,1]$ be the function where $f_n(x_\mu)=1$ and where $f_n(y)=0$ for $y\in K\setminus U_n$. Then $\int f_n|_Xd\mu=f_n(x_\mu)=1$. Since $f_n|_X$ is constant almost everywhere, there we conclude that $f_n|_X=1$ almost everywhere. In other words, there must be some $R_n\in\mathcal{F}$ with $f(y)=1$ for $y\in R_n$. But this implies that $R_n\subseteq U_n$. Therefore, $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty R_n\in\mathcal{F}$ but $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty R_n\subseteq\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty U_n\subseteq U$. This means that $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow x_\mu$.

Theorem: The set of points of the form $x_\mu$ for some $\{0,1\}$-measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is precisely the closure of $X$ in the $P$-space coreflection $(K)_{\aleph_1}$.

Proof: By the above result, since $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow x_\mu$ in the $P$-space coreflection $(K)_{\aleph_1}$, we can conclude that $x_\mu$ is in the closure of $X$ with respect to the topology $(K)_{\aleph_1}$.

Now, assume that $x_0$ is in the closure of $X$ in the $P$-space coreflection $(K)_{\aleph_1}$. We observe that whenever $R\in\mathcal{M}$, there is a $S\subseteq(K)_{\aleph_1}$ that is clopen with respect to the topology $(K)_{\aleph_1}$ where $S\cap X=R$. If $S_1,S_2\subseteq(K)_{\aleph_1}$ and
$S_1\cap X=S_2\cap X$ with $S_1,S_2$ clopen, the observe that $x_0\in S_1\Leftrightarrow x_0\in S_2$; otherwise, if $x_0\in S_1\setminus S_2$, then $S_1\setminus S_2$ would be a clopen subset of $(K)_{\aleph_1}$ that contains $x_0$ but which does not intersect $X$. Therefore, define a $\{0,1\}$-measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ where we set $\mu(S\cap X)=0$ whenever $S\cap X\in\mathcal{M}$, $S$ is clopen in $(K)_{\aleph_1}$, and $x_0\not\in S$, and where we set $\mu(S\cap X)=1$ whenever $S\cap X\in\mathcal{M}$, $S$ is clopen in $(K)_{\aleph_1}$, and $x_0\in S$.

I now claim that $x_0=x_{\mu}$. Suppose that $f:K\rightarrow[0,1]$ is continuous with respect to the original compact topology on $K$. We observe that $S=\{k\in K:f(k)=f(x_0)\}$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ that is clopen with respect to $(K)_{\aleph_1}$. Therefore, $S\cap X\in\mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(S\cap X)=1$, so $f(x)=f(x_0)$ for $\mu$-almost all $x\in X$. Thus, $\int f|_Xd\mu=f(x_0)$. We may now conclude that $x_0=x_\mu$.

Q.E.D.

Therefore, every $\{0,1\}$-measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is a Dirac point evaluation measure precisely when $X$ is closed in the $P$-space coreflection $(X)_{\aleph_1}$.

Example 0: If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then recall that the Baire $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by the sets $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ for some continuous $f:X\rightarrow[0,1]$. If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then every $\{0,1\}$-measure on the Baire $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is a point-evaluation Dirac measure.

Example 1: If $X$ is an uncountable discrete space, then let $K$ denote the one-point compactification $X\cup\{\infty\}$. Then $R\in\mathcal{M}$ if and only if $R$ is countable or $R^c$ is countable. Then the space $X$ is not closed in the one-point Lindelofification $(K)_{\aleph_1}$, so there is a $\{0,1\}$-measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ that is not the Dirac measure. In this case, $\mu(R)=0$ whenever $R$ is countable and $\mu(R)=1$ for uncountable $R$.

Example 2: Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Then let $\mathcal{N}$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Then since every $\{0,1\}$-measure on $\mathcal{M}$ is a point evaluation mapping, we can conclude that every $\{0,1\}$-measure on $\mathcal{N}$ is also a point evaluation mapping. We can produce a result that is much better than this though. The smallest cardinality $\kappa$ where there is some $\{0,1\}$-measure $\mu$ on $P(\kappa)$ that is not a Dirac measure is the first uncountable measurable cardinal which is a prominent location on the large cardinal hierarchy.